# How do you Map a Cucumber DataTable to Scala?

Tags: scala, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Code:

```
val someVariableIWantToSave    //I do not know what to do here

When("""^this request is sent to the XYZ service:$"""){ (requestData:DataTable) =>
 //// we might want to do somethign else with Datatable in the mapping of the       feature, nothing yet
var someVariableIWantToSave = requestData.asMaps()

}
```

I mean the asMaps method returns a List[Map[String,String]] type and I want to save it to the someVariableIWantToSave val  so I can use it in other steps, but I am not sure what to initialize it to and how to map it properly without a lot of code noise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "save something to a `val`", because `val`s can't be changed. Since you just get request data in this step and not in others, you should just have

```
When("""^this request is sent to the XYZ service:$"""){ (requestData:DataTable) =>
  val someVariableIWantToSave = requestData.asMaps()
  // do something with someVariableIWantToSave
}
```

Comment: i want to use that request data in other steps

Answer (score 0):

this was my solution.  Since this is just test code using var is Ok here..  i set it to the global in the test and then other Steps can use it...

```
var request: java.util.List[java.util.Map[String, String]] = _

When("""^this request is sent to the blah service:$"""){ (requestData:DataTable) =>
request = requestData.asMaps() 
}
```

`